# Canceling low frequency high amplitude noise signal

Tags: filtering, signal-processing, frequency, noise

I am currently collecting data from a power meter Keysight N7744A to be exact. The issue is that over the course around every 5 minutes (after collecting an hour of data) the data fluctuate over 20%. My goal is to take a single measurement and being able to guarantee that it is within 5% (>0.25dB) of the true value which can be obtained by averaging over the period of 5 minutes. However, this will impact performance by too much... A measurement is collected in 400ms.

Any thoughts on how I can cancel this extra low frequency but high amplitude noise signal? Thanks!

I have attached the data just in case I couldn't explain myself. It has 10k data points collected over 1+hours where each measurements takes ~400ms. [data.dat](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bydlaqpr3Ln8R2tRQXY2ejcwUW8)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a high pass filter would work.